# ZFS - only one single disk/by-id for two nvm devices

Tags: linux, disk, raid, zfs

I am trying to use best practices to setup a mirrored zfs pool on a ubuntu 20.04 server.

My hardware is 2x 1TB nvme in an external USB-C enclosure GEN2 SSD enclosure.

My issue is both disks seem to have the same disk id!
So I am able to create the pool using sda and sdb but is unstable after reboot the pool gets lost. To show the case I dumped devices properties in files and made fiff.

As you can see below disk by-id are exactly matching whereas disk path are different.

Even a workaround would be welcome.

```
sudo udevadm info --name=/dev/sda --query=property > sda
sudo udevadm info --name=/dev/sdb --query=property > sdb

diff sda sdb

1,2c1,2
< DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda
< DEVNAME=/dev/sda
---
> DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:1/block/sdb
> DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
5c5
< MINOR=0
---
> MINOR=16
7c7
< USEC_INITIALIZED=1630003
---
> USEC_INITIALIZED=1626316
31,33c31,33
< ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:**0**
< ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
< ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=2decf1ce-947b-9548-bef4-0e315c078f4f
---
> ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:**1**
> ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_1
> ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=ace78582-634a-b340-8ac5-3db5984afc5f
35c35
< DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000000000000001 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SASMT_ASM1352R-PM_3000CCCCBBBBAAAA /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000000000000001
---
> DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000000000000001 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SASMT_ASM1352R-PM_3000CCCCBBBBAAAA /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000000000000001 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:1
```

Comment: How do you create the `zfs` pool?

Comment: As a workaround, I use device names. sudo zpool create -f -o ashift=12 -m /home/gravity/.gravity zpool0 mirror /dev/sda /dev/sdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to:

- Determine the manufacturer and serial numbers of your drives
- Create a GPT partition table (or "scheme") on each drive
- Create a ZFS data partition on each drive, and name the partition in such a way as to reflect the manufacturer (possibly abbreviated) and serial number of that drive

For instance, if you want to create a mirror of two Western Digital drives, serial number `WD-WMC1S5694795` and `WD-WMC1S5688675`, then create identically-sized GPT partitions on each drive, and label the partition something like `data-WD-WMC1S5694795` and `data-WD-WMC1S5688675`, respectively.  Be sure to get them labeled correctly, or this time spent is useless.  Fortunately, these serial numbers already incorporate a leading `WD-` so the manufacturer is already encoded.  Including the abbreviated manufacturer in the label simply protects against the remotely possible situation that you would have two drives with identical serial numbers from different manufacturers.  Unlikely to happen, so use your discretion as to whether to encode the manufacturer in the partition label.

This will give you `/dev` entries under `/dev/disk/by-partlabel/` which you can then use to construct your pool:

```
# zpool create tank mirror /dev/disk/by-partlabel/data-WD-WMC1S5694795 \
                           /dev/disk/by-partlabel/data-WD-WMC1S5688675
# zpool status tank
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 23h36m with 0 errors on Wed Dec 1 16:00:38 2021
config:

    NAME                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank                      ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                ONLINE       0     0     0
        data-WD-WMC1S5694795  ONLINE       0     0     0
        data-WD-WMC1S5688675  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Now when one of the drives fails, you'll know exactly which one to replace, because the human-readable serial number appears on the outside of the drive.

Comment: thank you, worked perfectly fined.

Comment: @romadr Thank you, please read: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: crystal clear, checked and accepted. gpt were already created and I just had to mirror them in the pool.

Comment: @romadr Thank you, glad to hear it was easy.  The trouble with `UUID` is it's not visible to the human eye.  And of course, using `sda` and `sdb` can cause problems if you add drives or import the pool on a different host. So to to be able to ***visually*** identify a failed drive based on the `zpool` output, using the serial number from the drive label is the best practice I'm aware of.  Cheers!